# Android: TableLayout. Align in the row at the middle

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Please, see XML

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
    <TableRow android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tmp0"
            android:id="@+id/startButton">
        </ImageButton></TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="3"></TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image]

What properties are missed or mistakengly set to set ImageButton at the middle of the second row? (both, vertical and horizontal)

How to make equal row height and width?

I was searching in the question/answers base without success..

==========================

UPDATE:

To place Button at the middle the second row should be marked up as follows:

> ```
> <TableRow
>     **android:gravity="center"**
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_weight="1"
>     android:weightSum="3">
>     <ImageButton
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="@drawable/tmp0"
>         android:id="@+id/startButton">
>     </ImageButton>
> </TableRow>
> ```

Pls, look what happend, it's not correct of course:
[image]

But how to make rows height equal still do not understand.

Second row now formatted as follows, but in Designer it is the same as on the second pic

```
<TableRow
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tmp0"
        android:id="@+id/startButton">
    </ImageButton>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I think for TableRow to fix vertical in your whole screen with equal height for each row would not be possible untill you make all TableRow same. This is what TableLayout and TableRow behaves.See this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will equally divide your rows vertically.

Now just do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <!--<Button-->
                <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:text="Button" />-->

            <!--<Button-->
                <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:text="Button" />-->

            <!--<Button-->
                <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:text="Button" />-->
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <!--<Button-->
                <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:text="Button" />-->

            <!--<Button-->
                <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:text="Button" />-->

            <!--<Button-->
                <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:text="Button" />-->
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It will give more weight to second row.

**OLD**

Here you go.

Need to set `android:gravity="center"` in your second row

```
<?xml version=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"></ImageButton>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3"></TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Just try above code. It is showing your imageButton in center of your second row.

Comment: pls, look the UPDATE.. Image at the center, but button itself - left :)

Comment: No its not going to happen. Try to refresh layout

Comment: even reloaded studio. same. can get access to my pc

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken the second Row needs `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: I see, but your second row width is still wrap_content, not match_parent.

Comment: Have you tested this? not just looking onthe layout designer?

Comment: <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3">

Comment: I reloaded Androis studio ll it looks like on the last imagr

Comment: I understand what it looks like, is it behaving the sameway in the emulator?

Comment: thank you Tony.. you and Andi both right. gravity=center and also what you see on Designer is not exactly what it is on emulator.